# Cancelled mail ics showing "not supported"

Tags: outlook, office365

Canceled invitation emails send to outlook has an attachment "not supported". This is the ics i'm using for cancel email invitation. Could someone help me to understand what i'm missing here.

PS: Gmail is able to parse this ics and it is removing the event from calendar.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:CANCEL
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:fwefgWuxV6DNc1@QnzyZWc38uhPXw2
DTSTART:20190709T084500Z
DTEND:20190709T094500Z
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=DECLINED:mailto:p
 rhrsei@helonp.com
CREATED:20190709T082113Z
DESCRIPTION:\nanfirst anlast has can
 celled this meeting.\n\n************************************************\n
 \nMessage/Description: canceled \n\n\n************************************
 ************\n\nHelop Company\n
DTSTAMP:20190709T082204Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20190709T082205Z
LOCATION:
ORGANIZER:mailto:reiuhfoiwetransf@helonp.com
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CANCELLED
SUMMARY:asia singapaore
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The above is working with an outlook exchange server, but it is failing on o365 desktop client and even in office web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a same issue recently and just figured out the solution.
Looks like Microsoft has updated how they valuate Ical emails.

So it's not the ICS file that's corrupted, but if you're sending out a cancellation, you'll probably have some header that may say method=REQUEST. This works on all platforms but looks like Microsoft is checking if this is method=CANCEL for cancellation emails.

If you have a header of method=REQUEST and your ICS file is meant to cancel a meeting, it will then be corrupt. You'll have to change it to method=CANCEL.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah i'm sending the header as **method:cancel**, despite sending this, microsoft outlook fails to parse this.

Comment: I was sending contentType as text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset="utf-8" now i changed this to text/calendar; method=CANCEL; charset="utf-8. It is working. thanks @bhood1992

Comment: where were u sending it? because it is still not working for me