# How can I use an ICS file for multiple calendar deletes?

Tags: icalendar

I have a working ICS file that creates Outlook entries containing multiple vevent sections. New entries work fine.

How can I use a single ICS file with multiple vevents for deleting multiple entries without any user prompts? The best I have so far is the 1st vevent prompts for calendar removal of the 1st vevent, and all others are ignored in the file. This question is for O365 specifically.

The UID attributes match, the sequence is bumped by 1 on the deletion file for both vevents & the dtstamp attribute is updated to a later timestamp on both vevents in the file

The ICS file can have >100 vevent entries that are emailed as an attachment & they can be changed or deleted in  bulk also in a single ICS file. Adding works. Deleting has not. They'll drag & drop the attached ICS file just like they do when the new entries are added.

(been pulling my hair out with multiple deletions in 1 file!! )

Some ICS delete snippets:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
ORGANIZER:someemailaddress@thecompany.com
METHOD:CANCEL
...
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
STATUS:CANCELLED
...
SEQUENCE:1 (the creating sequence is 0) 
...
END:VEVENT



BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:someemailaddress@thecompany.com
STATUS:CANCELLED
...
SEQUENCE:1 (the creating sequence is 0)
...
END:VEVENT



END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Does ics header also have method cancel as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950398/cancelled-mail-ics-showing-not-supported ?

Comment: Sure does (I included that in my description of the file also. )

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcical/7befe35d-0652-447f-a780-d5fd5b879d38   states "In the case where the METHOD property is set to 'REQUEST', 'REPLY', or 'CANCEL', the VCALENDAR component MUST define exactly one appointment"

Cancellations are limited to 1 vevent in the vcalendar section, and only 1 vcalendar section per ICS file.

I'm seriously thinking I'm just stuck! (it's an app redesign now to figure out a "plan B"